# Why is と being used after the past tense in this sentence?

Tags: particles, particle-と

> 鳥が警戒声というものを発する。敵が**来たと**仲間たちに教えるために。

I thought it was only used after 辞書形 in these cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it is being used as a quotation.
「敵が来た」と仲間たちに教えるために。

Same was as
「食べたくない」とお母さんに言いました。